Oracle 12c: How can the LENGTH() of a VARCHAR2 value be more than its size?
Today I SELECTed the LENGTH() of a value in a VARCHAR2(1) column and got "5" even though it sure looks like 1 character to me when I SELECT the column directly in PLSQL Developer (it has the value '0' as far as I can tell).  What can I check to figure this out?  Seems bonkers to me and I can't think of what I might be missing.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] that replicates the problem with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statement for your sample data; the output of SELECT column_name, DUMP(column_name) FROM your_table; and the SELECT statement that you use to generate the LENGTH.

first thing I do with a situation like this is do select 'Z' || field_name || 'Z' from yourtable.  This will show if there are non-printable charachters (eg spaces) before or after the value of 0 that it is currently returning.

Most likely there is some unvisible character stored with the visible one. Look at a sample below:
WITH
    tbl (ID, A_VARCHAR) AS
        ( Select 1, 'G' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'E' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, '0' || Chr(13) From Dual Union All
          Select 4, '0' From Dual
        )
Select ID, A_VARCHAR, Length(A_VARCHAR) "LEN_CHAR", LengthB(A_VARCHAR) "LEN_BYTE"
From   tbl
/*
        ID A   LEN_CHAR   LEN_BYTE
---------- - ---------- ----------
         1 G          1          1
         2 E          1          1
         3 0          2          2
         4 0          1          1 */

You can check it using DUMP
Select ID, A_VARCHAR, DUMP(A_VARCHAR) "DMP"
From   tbl
/*
        ID A_VARCHAR DMP   
---------- --------- --------------------
1          G         Typ=1 Len=1: 71
2          E         Typ=1 Len=1: 69
3          0         Typ=1 Len=2: 48,13   <--- two bytes [48, 13] 13 is CR character
4          0         Typ=1 Len=1: 48      */

Other (opposite) posibility is that you are dealing with multibyte characters where the length in bytes is bigger than length in characters. Oracle treats VARCHAR2 either as a CHAR or as a BYTE depending on NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter (more about it here). You can check your session's NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter value (and all others) using:
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS;

Below is small example where you can see the difference of the two NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter values:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR
WITH
    tbl (ID, A_VARCHAR) AS
        ( Select 1, CAST('G' as VarChar2(1)) From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, CAST('E' as VarChar2(1)) From Dual Union All
          Select 3, CAST('ü' as VarChar2(1)) From Dual Union All
          Select 4, CAST('€' as VarChar2(1)) From Dual
        )
Select ID, A_VARCHAR, Length(A_VARCHAR) "LEN_CHAR", LengthB(A_VARCHAR) "LEN_BYTE"
From   tbl
/*   R e s u l t : 
        ID A   LEN_CHAR   LEN_BYTE
---------- - ---------- ----------
         1 G          1          1
         2 E          1          1
         3 ü          1          2
         4 €          1          3  */

Above configuration NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR means that VARCHAR2(1) datatype will store 1 character no metter how many bytes that character is long.
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTE
/*    R e s u l t :    (of the same above query)
        ID A   LEN_CHAR   LEN_BYTE
---------- - ---------- ----------
         1 G          1          1
         2 E          1          1
         3                        
         4                          */

Above configuration NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTE means that VARCHAR2(1) datatype will store 1 character of the length of 1 byte and it is not possible to store any multibyte character.
